# CRF++: Yet Another CRF Tool Kit

Tags: java, c++

When I use `CRF++` toolkit for the first time. I have installed it and when I run the `crflearn` command I'am getting this message :

> CRF++: Yet Another CRF Tool Kit Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Taku Kudo, All rights reserved.  encoder.cpp(340) [feature_index.open(templfile, trainfile)] feature_index.cpp(135) [ifs] open failed: template_file

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The package is pretty well documented [here](http://taku910.github.io/crfpp/)

Can you give the full command you tried to use?

The pattern is `crf_learn -t [template_file] [data_file_in_the_right_format]`

The package comes with an example template file, here's the head of mine:

> U00:%x[-5,0]
>
> U01:%x[-4,0]
>
> U02:%x[-3,0]
>
> U03:%x[-2,0]
>
> U04:%x[-1,0]
>
> U05:%x[0,0]

The data needs to be in a tab delimited format with each data point represented by a row, each column is the feature value for that row and the final column is your gold standard label.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You put wrong file path for template featurefile and model. So, put these files inside CRF-PP folder and fire the crf_learn command. Hope this will solve your issue.